# Is it safe to fetch data using multi threading?

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I am new to multi-threading.

- I have a database with 8 tables on the server.
- I connect to the database directly using an Android device.
- I want to get data from the server and insert it into a client database (SQLite).
- I have a function that inserts all of the data from the server into the client, and I call that function for every table.

Is it safe to make 8 threads, one for every table? I use [`TTask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Threading.TTask).

Comment: Depends on how "safe" you design such threads.

Comment: how to design  a safe thread in this situation

Comment: That's an *extremely* broad question. There are literally entire books answering that question.

Comment: it's not advisable to connect to the database directly from an Android device.

Comment: Just to add on what @nolaspeaker is advising, the best way to get data is to have a Web API which talks to the database, and have your client (Android) calling the API to get whatever data you need.

Comment: Indeed. There are lots of ways to create data servers, and just as many ways to connect to them from an Android device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theoretically it should be safe, assuming each table is accessed using a separate thread and no data is shared between the threads.

It should be safe even if you slightly "mess up", since the databases are likely to be thread safe.

However, your internal code might not be thread safe, so we don't really know.